# How to update and create a new json from an existing

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a js code that came in with a very weird requirement that I'm unable to solve it.

So there is a JSON array object, let's say `a` with a couple of `key - values` in it. and I've got another JSON, say `b`, which is coming from an endpoint, now `b's` one of the values is a key in `a`. I need to add `a` as a child of `b`, update the `a` values according to the value returned by `b` and create a new JSON. And the condition to update is, all the JSON objects before the object match returned by `b`, I want to update the value to `complete`, Including the returned match. I know this is a lot to digest.

Here is a minimalistic example of my JSONs.

```
var a = [{"a":"Not Started"},{"b":"Not Started"},{"c":"Not Started"},{"d":"Not Started"},{"e":"Not Started"}]

var b = [{"Id":1, "Stage":"c"}]
```

So the Expected output should look like.

```
[{"Id":1, "Stages":[{"a":"complete"},{"b":"complete"},{"c":"complete"},{"d":"Not Started"},{"e":"Not Started"}]}]
```

Since the stage returned in `b` is `c`, everything in `a` before `c` (`c` included), value should be updated to `complete`.

This is very tricky, please let me know how can I solve this.

Thanks

Comment: _"So there is a JSON array object..."_ - No, [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) nor a "JSON array object". That's a plain old array of objects.

Comment: `b.Stages = a`?

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox, `b` returns only one stage. where I need to update the value before the returned stage variable.  Please look at the example I provided. and please let me know if it is unclear. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Andreas, thanks for that link.

Comment: Add `a` to `b` (`b.Stages = a`) and then modify the elements in `b.Stages` until you find an object with a property that matches the value of `b[0].Stage`. A loop shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Yes @Andreas,  using `find()`, I can update the value in `a` matching stage in `b`. But how about the before objects in `a` that are matching `b`.

Comment: Oh, Now I gotcha @Andreas, lemme give it a shot. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
var a = [{"a":"Not Started"},{"b":"Not Started"},{"c":"Not Started"},{"d":"Not Started"},{"e":"Not Started"}];

var b = [{"Id":1, "Stage":"c"}];


b[0].Stage = a;

console.log(b);
```